# Disable WiFi management on Windows 8 using Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, wifi

We have a domain composed by a Windows Server 2012R2 that controls 40 laptop with Windows 8 connected via WiFi.
Our goal is to prevent users to disconnect the wifi or, even worst, connect to other networks.

We restrict the network policies as suggest 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732613(v=ws.10).aspx, and http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/03/how-to-use-group-policy-to-blackwhite-list-wireless-networks-in-vista-windows-7/

This worked well using Windows Vista as client, but with Windows 8 it didn't work. The main problem is that any user can disconnect the wifi using the **right sidebar**, and also disconnect to the network.

Do you know if there are other kind of policies to prevent that? Or do you know a way to completely disable the right windows 8 sidebar?

Thanks

Comment: you'll need a third party tool to FULLY disable the win8 charms bar. but this should also do the trick (but not completely) in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell` set `DisableCharmsHint` to `1` with this registry entry, the charms bar only appears wenn you really point to the upper right corner and slide down with the mouse

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Anyway that command disable the charms bar, but not the wifi sidebar, the one that appears when you click on the network icon in the tray bar. Using that sidebar, users can turn off the wifi

Answer (score 1):

We also had kind of the same problem. All that we did was disabling WiFi and Bluetooth through device manager and restricting users to Local Users group so that they might not be able to install/uninstall or enable/disable devices. This is a much simple by effective way (as proved to us).

We had also even tried to delete the driver files from system32 and system32\drivers folders but when the device manager is refreshed, windows 8.1 quickly re-installs the drivers from no-where.

So we simply disabled the devices from Device Manager.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However in our setting we cannot disable the wifi, since the laptops are wireless connected to the server.